# ImportError: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found required by PIL on CPanel

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, cpanel

I am trying to install a python application to cpanel shared hosting.
I was experiencing an error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name _imaging
```

I then fould a solution to install PILLOW using:

```
pip install --platform=manylinux2014_x86_64 --only-binary=:all: --target /upgrade/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages pillow
```

Now I get an error:

```
ImportError: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found required by PIL
```

How do I resolve this?

Tried Installing PILLOW from an already built wheel